# Virtual console (login) does not work after upgrade (Arch)

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, upgrade

I am unable to interact with the virtual console after upgrading my Arch system today with `sudo pacman -Syu` to 6.1.6. I have had this system for 2+ years and it has always worked fine. It worked immediately after the upgrade, but when I rebooted keystrokes no longer were being processed by the virtual console so I was unable to login locally. Note that the system boots correctly, it's just that the virtual console does not work. I tried using a different keyboard, but no luck with that. Note that the keyboard works normally in BIOS and if I boot the same machine with an Arch live CD and chroot into 6.1.6 environment, the keyboard works fine.

The process involved (login) is listed as follows via ps:

```
/sbin/agetty -o -p -- \u --noclear - linux
```

I can SSH into the machine and everything appears normal from the command line. If I do a systemctl -b it just shows ACPI errors and other random stuff, nothing that seems to be keyboard or USB related.

How can I diagnose this problem?

Note that the usbutils package is installed as well as the xhci package. **lsusb** shows the keyboard to be detected as a valid USB device and appears normal. There were no boot log entries that appeared to be keyboard related. The Topre keyboard as shown below is not working (although other usb devices might not work, I don't know because I can't interact directly with the machine anymore).

udevadm tests show that when the keyboard is plugged in or removed, then events for the "new device" are generated, but when keystrokes are made, no events show up in the udev monitor, so it might be a kernel problem.

evtest is clearly registering events from the keyboard (shown as the third paste below), so it might be some kind of terminal issue maybe? If evtest receives keystrokes but udevadm does not, what does that imply?

It would be useful if someone could explain the end-to-end process for handling keystrokes and how to check at each step how and if the keystroke is being handled.

```
me@computer:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0853:0145 Topre Corporation REALFORCE 87 US
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04b8:013a Seiko Epson Corp. GT-X820 [Perfection V600 Photo]
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:0843 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C930e
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

me@computer:~$ lsusb -t
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 10000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 4, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 4, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

evtest shows that events are being received from the keyboard:

```
Event: time 1674156563.381863, -------------- SYN_REPORT ------------
Event: time 1674156563.523858, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 70004
Event: time 1674156563.523858, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 30 (KEY_A), value 0
```

Note that I can restart the login process (sudo systemctl restart agetty@tty1) and it restarts but still accepts no keyboard input. dmesg has normal content and no obvious errors.

Comment: hmm. it's weird you don't have encrypted /root partitions right ? if you do can you verify you have `HOOKS=(base udev autodetect modconf block keyboard encrypt filesystems fsck)` in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf` keyboard should be before encrypt hook

Comment: Can you plug into the another port? The snd-usb-audio suspicious for me.

Comment: @K-att- I have tried plugging in different keyboards to different USB sockets. None of them work.

Comment: The different means not into the bus01?

Comment: @K-att- I don't know, there are several different sets of USB sockets on the back of the computer. I tried different ones. Look, there is nothing wrong with the hardware. It is clearly an OS issue because the problem happened after a system update.

Comment: You can check it with the lsusb -t. I just want to know, the uvcvideo or the audio driver caused your problem, or not.

Comment: Output of mine `/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/3p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 10000M
`

Comment: @don_crissti If I use udevadm monitor and then unplug and plug in the computer I get the normal reaction, however, if I type keys at the keyboard then udevadm does not seem to be receiving the keystrokes.

Comment: You should try to chroot and install another kernel (e.g. [`linux-lts`](https://archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/linux-lts/) and then reboot and use that one. As we have no diagnostic/warning ATM it's nearly impossible to troubleshoot this issue...

Comment: Is the system bootet to X? If yes, post Xorg log and switch to [multi-user.target](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd#Change_default_target_to_boot_into) and report if it works there.

Comment: @Freddy No it boots to a virtual console.

Comment: Could be kernel related, there was another guy with a Topre keyboard with a [similar problem](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=251844). Can you add this `usbcore.quirks=0853:0145:gki` thing to your kernel parameters or try a different kernel?

Comment: @Freddy I saw that post. I tested the computer with other keyboards that are not Topre and had the same problem.

Comment: You have to start somewhere. If there was a kernel update, [downgrade](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/downgrading_packages) it to the previous version. If that doesn't help, downgrade all packages to the version you had before the last update. Post the list of upgraded packages from `/var/log/pacman.log`, post `dmesg` output.

Comment: If evtest is registering keyboard events, it's not a hardware or kernel problem. Check your /etc/console-setup, /etc/vconsole.conf, /etc/default/console-setup, and /etc/default/keyboard configuration files. Also, try running X11 and see if keyboard input works there.

Comment: @LennonMcLean I usually run Sway on that machine, but only after I login first to the virtual console. Are you suggesting I install an x-based desktop and then somehow start it remotely via ssh, or should I try to start Sway (which is already installed) remotely? If so, how do I start it on the machine if I can't login? Is there a way to do that remotely?

Comment: You can make it auto login and start sway: see [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/getty) and [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xinit) (Yes the page is for X but the point is the method to start *something* automatically.)

Comment: Show us a `dmesg`and/or `jougrnalctl` where keboard is. It may show some kind of error.

Comment: @tukan There is no error in the logs, as I said. You can clearly see that evtest is receiving events per the question text, so it is not a keyboard issue. Also, as I said once again, I tested the machine with multiple keyboards from different manufacturers.

Comment: Ok. Do you have USBGuard installed?

Comment: @tukan "pacman -Qs usbguard" returns nothing. which also returns negative.

Comment: Got me thinking if the whole USB subsystem is consistent. Does the other USB devices work? Like USB Camera, mouse or flashdrive?

Comment: @tukan If I plug in a USB flash drive, I get the usual dmesg "attached removable drive" log messages. If I then give the command lsusb it lists the drive (as well as the keyboard). However, the drive does not appear to be mounted. For example, mounts gives nothing, nor does cat /proc/mounts. Also, lsblk shows the device but no path indicating the device is attached but not mounted. The directory /run/media is empty, once again indicating it is not mounted.

Comment: Based on that I'm pretty sure your USB subsystem is broken. If you boot from liveCD/USB does the keyboard work or the flashdrive?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** thanks to @don_crissti who noticed that the OP has already tried what I was suggesting in the comments section (I have missed that):

> "Note that the keyboard works normally in BIOS and if I boot the same
> machine with an Arch live CD and chroot into 6.1.6 environment, the
> keyboard works fine.

### The original slightly modified answer

Based on your posts in the comments section it is pretty safe to say that you have your USB subsystem broken.  You will need to sanitize your system to check what went wrong during the upgrade or return to a backup before the upgrade.  If everything other will fail, make a backup of everything you need like */home* */etc* etc. and reinstall the system.

It is always hard to virtually debug system I/we never saw.  This is I think (IMHO) the most information you can get as I/we did not see any error occurring which could be an indication of any issue.

Comment: _"Note that the keyboard works normally in BIOS and if I boot the same machine with an Arch live CD and chroot into 6.1.6 environment, the keyboard works fine."_

Comment: @don_crissti BIOS has its own keyboard/USB handling, that is independent of the OS.  I have missed the try with the arch live.  I will adjust the answer for that. Thank you for the comment

Answer (score -3):

If you can ssh into the Box try strace -f -p PID the login process and see if the process gets data from the keyboard.

Comment: If I do that, it returns "pselect6(5, [0 4], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL", then if I type characters at the keyboard, nothing happens.